# how to download a folder from S3 in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download a folder as zip file from S3.

$zip =

```
 new \ZipArchive();
$zipfilename = sys_get_temp_dir().'\Admissionform_'.$school_id.'_'.$formfor_id.'.zip';
$zip->open($zipfilename, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
if ($s3->exists($Mainpath)) {
$file = Files::select('path', 'extension')->find($file_id);
$pathToFile = $file->path;
$content = $s3->get($pathToFile);
$zip->addFromString($zipfilename.$filename, file_get_contents($pathToFile));
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($zipfilename);
```

how to go forward?

Comment: how are you responding in the controller? try `return response()->download($zipfilename)`

Answer (score 0):

Some issues on your code, its missing:

import required classes in php, initialize the variable and set correct path zip archive. Here the code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Models\Files; // Replace 'App\Models\Files' with the actual namespace of your Files model if it's different.

// Initialize the filename
$filename = 'AdmissionForm_' . $school_id . '_' . $formfor_id;

$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zipfilename = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename . '.zip';
$zip->open($zipfilename, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
if ($s3->exists($Mainpath)) {
    $file = Files::select('path', 'extension')->find($file_id);
    $pathToFile = $file->path;
    $content = $s3->get($pathToFile);
    // Add the file to the zip using its basename as the filename within the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($pathToFile), $content);
}
$zip->close();

// Set the correct headers to force download the zip file
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename . '.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($zipfilename);
```

Make sure to replace 'App\Models\Files' with the correct namespace of your Files model. Additionally, ensure that you have set up the S3 configuration correctly in your Laravel application and that you have the necessary permissions to access the S3 bucket and the file you want to download.

With these changes, the corrected code should now allow you to download the folder as a zip file from S3.